# Remove button border on tab c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, button, tabs, border

I have a button on my form that has flat style applied and uses a background image, I have removed all borders from the button, but when I tab onto the button from another control a black border appears around the button.

This can be seen in the image below. On the left is the button with black border on the right is a different button but shows how the cancel button should look.

[image: Buttons]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148729/how-to-set-change-remove-focus-style-on-a-button-in-c

Comment: You have to do something reasonable to indicate the focus.  Which is what the black rectangle is intended to do.  Completely removing it just gets users lost and frustrated when using your UI.

Comment: I agree with hans, even if you remove the border, you should think of adding a highlight (image change with a brighter one on focus or something else). working around with UI that users are used to is not a good idea unless you are 100% sure what you are doing.

Comment: @Sean87 Hi Sean & Hans, I do intend on adding a highlight to the button when it is selected, I would leave the border only it doesn't look good.

Answer (score 3):

I do not get this border, if I set the `BoderSize` to `0` in the `FlatAppearance` section.

---

Further investigation shows that this border appears only when the button is the default button. You can create your own button, which does never show this border like this

```
public class NoNotifyButton: System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    public override void NotifyDefault(bool value)
    {
    }
}
```

Note: `NotifyDefault` remains intentionally empty.

Comment: Hi,

I tried doing this using the method here (its the highlighted answer) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/winforms/thread/8d85e6dd-18ad-4503-9f0a-731a8d73d570 

But the problem still persists.

Comment: Note: There is a black border, which is drawn around the default button and a gray border, which is drawn around focused buttons. My code makes the black border disappear; however, the gray one remains.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a new button class using `IButtonControl` and change `NotifyDefault` to false:

```
base.NotifyDefault(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a derived class.
You can set the ForeColor to be the same as parent control BackColor.
As follows :

```
btn1.ForeColor = btn1.Parent.BackColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it setting the button property "ForeColor" to transparent

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this by setting the button TabStop property to False and then using this code on the button click event

```
private void sendBackTab()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("+{TAB}");
        }
```