# Remove dotted line on button

Tags: c#, winforms

How do you remove the dotted line that appears on buttons when they are selected (either via tab or by clicking them)?

This question is for `winforms` - any help is appreciated.

[image]

Edit: I apologize for the duplicate question. I did search for an answer, but I did not know this issue was due to the 'focus' of the button. As I result I was not finding the appropriate answers.

Comment: Why has this question been voted to be closed? It is a valid question.

Comment: When a button is 'selected'. Try tabbing through a windows forms application until a button is selected - you'll see the dotted line that I am referring to.

Comment: what you are asking is a method to override the default on focus behavior of the button control. You basically have to sub-class or override the default handling of button's WindowProcedure so that you can do your own painting when processing the windows message WM_PAINT

Comment: Developers tend to be highly objective "T"'s (see myers-briggs). Start talking about feelings might as well slap on the scarlet letter.  Consider re-phrasing your questions with technical details as opposed to how you feel about the outcome.

Comment: The zeal found on Stack Overflow can be staggering at times...

Comment: From an accessible point-of-view you shouldn't remove the UI showing where the focus is. In this case, how do you know where the focus is using only your keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your `Button` gains focus. It is possible to remove it but that means giving the focus to something else when your button's focus [Enter event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx) is triggered.

```
private void button1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // give focus to something else
}
```

The problem with that is that you lose the ability to use the keyboard in order to select the button (using tab).

Moreover, a more correct approach would be to give focus to the last control that had focus instead of passing it fixed one.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to remove the focus from the button.

just call `Focus();` when the button is clicked.

Comment: The outline does not appear for windows 8. but it does for 7 and XP.

Answer (score 1):

create custom control add ShowFocusCues and build  to use

Example

```
public class button : System.Windows.Forms.Button
    {
        protected override bool ShowFocusCues
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for button border settings.

I do not get this border, if I set the `BorderSize` to `0` in the `FlatAppearance` section

From [Remove button border on tab c# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966462/remove-button-border-on-tab-c-sharp-winforms)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ShowFocusRectangle` peoperty to `false`.

Comment: The [System.Windows.Forms.Button](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button?view=netframework-4.8) has no property called `ShowFocusRectangle`. I guess you are refering to the DEV Express button.

Comment: Yes I'm referring to the DevExpress simpleButton.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer here that really works without having to hack (moving focus to another control) is Wongsathon Tuntanakan's answer.

I refer to his answer and, as a bit of extra, I've converted his code to VB:

```
Public Class YourButtonClass
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Button

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property ShowFocusCues As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```