# C# Winforms - Flat Button Style - Transparent Border

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I've recently created a new control - a flat button - so no border, transparent background, no mouse down color, etc. The problem is, once the app is compiled and running, a black border is around the transparent background. I am going to attach two images - the first is how it looks on the app while running and second is how it looks on the design screen (how i want it to look). I'd appreciate any help getting this border to go away. Thank you!

```
public FlatButton() : base()
{
    FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
    FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
    BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);    
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    Pen pen = new Pen(FlatAppearance.BorderColor, 0);
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width - 2, Size.Height - 2);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);   
}
```

[image: In App]

[image: In designer]

Comment: You could try setting NotifyDefault to false, as per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966462/remove-button-border-on-tab-c-sharp-winforms)?

Comment: Can't answer your question, but remember to `Dispose()` your `Pen`!

Comment: NotifyDefault did not work

Comment: `Borders` can't have a `Color.Transparent`. Cheating with  `Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255)` gets around the compiler/designer error message but still doesn't work. Maybe setting `BorderSize=0` will help?

Comment: It's enough to set `FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;` then `FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;`. Why do you want to override `OnPaint`?

Comment: Also: Drawing with a Transparent Color as you do will __not draw anything__ unless you also set `e.Graphics.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;`..

Answer (score 0):

Try setting TabStop = false; in the constructor of this FlatButton class.