# C# Winform: Remove the border from a standard button?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, border

Is it possible to remove the border of a standard C# `Button` ? I know that I could set the `FlatStyle` property to `Flat` and customize the `FlatAppearance` property to hide the border but I would prefer to use the `Standard` property to ensure that the control appears under all operating systems like a default `Button`. Did you have any suggestions how I can solve this issue? I am working with a Windows Forms Application.

Comment: are you working with winforms, wpf, ..etc.. ?

Comment: What do you mean standard property? You don't want to change FlatStyle but you want to change the "standard properties"?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966462/remove-button-border-on-tab-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: "Standard" is a member of the FlatStyle-Enumeration. I want keep the Standard property but without the border. This is important for the right appearance under different Windows versions.

Comment: @PeterAbolins I already read this but it doesn't worked for me.

Comment: The border is drawn by the renderer of the Button control, the code that implements its OnPaint() method.  That code is wrapped inside an adapter class, there are 13 of them.  Each dedicated to a specific button type and the FlatStyle.  Sadly Microsoft decided to make them all `internal`, so you can't monkey with them.  So you'd have to make your own, that can be as simple as a PictureBox.  Making it animate and focus-aware and implementing IButtonControl takes more work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an image and make it clickable, that is one way to avoid the borders, but there are several options. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows forms and trying to implement Flat UI, Material UI, Metro-Looking controls, you're in hell. It is has limited properties for customizations unless you know how to work with `Graphics` and `Animation`. You'll have to use imagebox or picture box and dynamically change its image on different events.

I'll suggest `WPF` or `Windows Presentation Foundation` for a more customizable User Interface.