# Remove blue outlining of buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, button, outlining

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set/change/remove focus style on a Button in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148729/how-to-set-change-remove-focus-style-on-a-button-in-c)

Is there a way to remove the blue outlining when a button is pressed/was pressed/is active?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Blue outlining]

Is there any way to hide it? I am using C# and winforms.

Comment: im pretty sure there is a .IsActive or .IsSelected attribute you could probably set to false

Comment: If you're wanting to hide the "focus" style, you're probably not too worried about accessibility requirements, and thus not concerned about keyboard compatibility. You could instead have a panel or other control with custom painting and response to the `OnClick` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amalgamating the answers from the duplicate question

```
public class NoFocusCueButton : Button
{
    public NoFocusCueButton() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }

    protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new class and inherit class `Button`, eg

```
public class OnetsButton : Button
{
    public OnetsButton()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: is enough. It simple but not more

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution now, it's not very sexy, but it works.
I just added an invisible button to the form and now everytime a button is clicked,
I select the invisible button. Works for me.