# Visual c++, correct synthax for ShowFocusCues

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, clr

i would like to set '`ShowFocusCues`' to false

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.showfocuscues(v=vs.80).aspx

```
protected public:
virtual property bool ShowFocusCues {
    bool get ();
}
```

[How to set/change/remove focus style on a Button in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148729/how-to-set-change-remove-focus-style-on-a-button-in-c)

i tried:

```
virtual property bool ShowFocusCues {
bool get ();
}

bool ShowFocusCues() override
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but both is wrong and complains about 'get'
i want to prevent the focus

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this.

```
protected override bool ShowFocusCues { get { return false; } }
```

This must be included in code of a control class that must hied focus rectangle from being drawn