# button release after mouse hovering out

Tags: vb.net

I have this six button[image]

After i press one button, for example i press settings it will open an new windows after i close that windows the button remain pressed.
[image]

Here are the settings button code:

```
  Private Sub btn_SETTINGS_MouseEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_SETTINGS.MouseEnter
    btn_SETTINGS.ForeColor = Color.White

End Sub

Private Sub btn_SETTINGS_MouseLeave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_SETTINGS.MouseLeave
    btn_SETTINGS.ForeColor = SystemColors.HotTrack




End Sub
Private Sub btn_SETTINGS_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_SETTINGS.Click
    OpenSettings()
End Sub
```

Any suggestion what can i do to fix this problem.

Comment: Maybe your button has simple the focus (I assume you are talking about a WinForms application)?

Comment: i forgot to mention my application is winForms app, and after my mouse will i want the button to be unpressed

Comment: One of the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148729/how-to-set-change-remove-focus-style-on-a-button-in-c show you how to "unpress" your button. As I told you, your button is not pressed. You are using the "flat" style, and the button with the focus is drawn with a different border size. But read this other answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this problem seems related to `Focus` that got set to the button when you pressed it. Very easy and quick fix of this problem is, change the focus of control to some other control. On the same side, add one `label` control which is of `Hidden` type say `lblHidden`. So when you're doing following code then change focus.

```
Private Sub btn_SETTINGS_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_SETTINGS.Click
    OpenSettings()
    Me.ActiveControl = lblHidden 
End Sub
```

This will change the focus to hidden control. However if you are doing any formatting change of button on click event then revert it back to original in above even.t

Comment: @user3223293 Did you create/add a label in your form? And set is visibility property to `False` and named it as `lblHidden`?

Comment: i get an error 'this' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: You did add a label? and when you are accessing it in code behind then it is not available?

Comment: a I have add a label and set visibility to false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87962/discussion-between-amnesh-goel-and-user3223293).

Comment: in VB is Me.ActiveControl = lblHidden :)

Comment: @user3223293 ohh, thnx, noted, I did it in C#, is this gone?